# Relationship between grams of root and content in a tea

Tags: everyday-chemistry, water, toxicity

When we make a tea from a some herb, what exactly is the relation between the weight of the herb/root stepped in hot water and how many grams/milligrams are in the tea.
For context and giving a specific example:
After reading about side effects of using nutmeg, I am always checking for any spice or herb or root I use.
For a concrete example ginger I am reading that there is an upper gram limit that above which side effects appear.
I am trying to understand if this would also pertain to tea and if for example we take 20 grams of ginger root grated and put it in hot water would that mean that there are 20 grams of ginger (somehow) in the tea?
What is the relationship here?

Comment: From first principles, there is impossible to determine for specific cases relation between the dry "tee" mass,  the mass of dissolved components in infusion and the mass of active components. It requires extensive experimental work in the particular scenarios. // There is also unclear relation between amount of absorbed active components from a given mass of herb if used directly(e.g. added to food) or if used for infusion. There are too many variables there.

Answer (score 1):

Like the previous answer, there isn't a way to know without performing some form of analysis. If someone else has done this sort of analysis, you could replicate the way they made their tea to have an idea of what yours might contain.

I think that there might be a deeper misunderstanding on your part.  Take ginger for example.  The ginger root is made up of hundreds (or probably thousands) of different chemical compounds. Some of these are the molecules that make up the cell walls (cellulose) and other fibres in root.  Some of these are the DNA and proteins that are part of any living thing. If the ginger is fresh, there will also be a lot of water.  So, 20 grams of ginger is not referring to 20 grams of one thing.

When you make a tea, you put the plant in hot water, and only some of the chemicals in the plant dissolve in water.  Which ones, and how much, depends on the plant, the temperature of the water and how much water vs plant material is used.

If you are concerned about potential health risks or side effects, you should look up reference material specific to teas made from those plants, not just the plants themselves.

I hope that helps.

Comment: It does help. When looking if there are any reports already about tea I found articles like this: https://senchateabar.com/blogs/blog/ginger-tea-benefits#:~:text=One%20cup%20of%20ginger%20tea,caused%20by%20bloating%20and%20cramps. here it says `One cup of ginger tea contains an average of 250 milligrams of ginger` but there is no reference of any lab analysis to back it up. This one https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4818021/ mentions `that 1000 mg is equivalent to one teaspoon (5 g) of freshly grated ginger extract,` has a reference but I can't access the full article

Comment: Do you think the second article is reliable i.e. they have followed the lab analysis you mention?

Comment: As far as I can see, the second reference is a reliable one, in that it is published in a peer-reviewed scientific journal. I don't have access to the article that they cite for the various equivalent doses of ginger, so I can't evaluate those.  The authors in the paper you refer to do point out that there are no real standards in regards to the active constituents of ginger.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, the answer is probably too complicated to answer without analysis of the specific tea.
The ingredients within the herb or root all have their own saturation levels. For example, the water will likely not be able to hold the same amount of sodium chloride when compared to sugar.
Different molecules also dissolve at different rates. Table salt is soluble in water, and so is limestone, but table salt dissolves much faster - partly due to its much higher saturation level.

One issue that makes it particularly complicated, however, is that these solutes affect each other. The chloride ions from the sodium chloride could, potentially, impact the solvation of potassium by limiting the rate at which it can be freed from its chloride ions.

And that's an oversimplification. There is actually a lot more to it than I just explained, but I hope my oversimplification can provide a little more clarity without requiring me to go too in depth.

TLDR; The most practical way to know would be to perform analysis of the tea you are curious about.

Comment: Does that mean that there is theoretically the possibility that if we have X grams of something stepped in hot water, we drink X grams of said thing when consuming the tea?

Comment: Only if X g of something is soluble in given volume of boiling water. "Soluble tea" is.